# How to make scatter plots in Python with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I want to make a scatter plot with `plotly`.

So i head to the official example on the plotly site: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/

I slightly modify the code (below) and put into a python file:

```py
import plotly.express as px


def main():
    scatter_plot()
    return


def scatter_plot():
    ''' make a scatter plot with plotly '''
    # x and y given as array_like objects
    fig = px.scatter(x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], y=[0, 1, 4, 9, 16])
    fig.show()
    
    return

# main guard idiom
if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

I expect to see a basic scatter plot show up.

Instead i see a tab on my browser launch with a local url: http://127.0.0.1:59326/

but the tab is blank:

```
This site can’t be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
```

What do i have to do to see the plot ?

edit:
if i do `pip install --upgrade nbformat` and then run in a jupyter notebook (in vscode) it works. But i would like to run in a *.py file.

Comment: Terminals don't show figures ?? I don't know how you would expect a figures to be "seen". Generally doing this in a notebook is exactly how you would go if you want to view charts from a python script such as this one. Anyhoo, see the getting started documentation section on static image support for more info. [getting started](https://plotly.com/python/getting-started/). They also refer you here: [static-image-export](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) and here: [interactive-html-export](https://plotly.com/python/interactive-html-export/)

Comment: @topsail,  appreciated.   i wanted to view the output with the `show()` before producing the `html`. But from the docs and what you have said, i guess that is not possible....  thanks.